# Mic not working?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CSGO I play competitive a lot so I use my mic. I use my computers mic not my headset. It works 90% of the time but the other 10% my teammates say it's just horrible static. Is there a certain reason for this or is it just my mic?

Comment: Is your game sound coming through your headset and not your speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not a certain answer. It could have some variables. For example it could be feedback however that doesn't normally create static. It could also be faulty wires. Try checking your mic setting on your OS and Steam. If you have another external mic that you can use and if that creates static then it's probably just your settings.